# Javascript - what should setting a value at index -1 in an array do?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been surprised to find that:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a[-1] = 4;
```

can have different results:

- in chrome -> `a` is then `[1, 2, 3]`
- in node -> `a` is then `[1, 2, 3, '-1': 4]`

what is the expected behavior, if any?

Comment: The result is the same in both of them; they just display it differently. In Chrome, `a[-1]` will still be `4`, and it won’t be “in” the array in either of them – just a regular old non-index property, like if you set `a.foo = 4`.

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Remember, a Javascript array is just an object that has `Array` as its prototype. You can set any property on it, just like any other object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result should be the same no matter what. Either one may display differently in the console, but in practice, the fashion in which values are displayed in the console shouldn't really have any bearings on the underlying mechanics. In this case, the effect is the same: the property named `-1` is set to 4. However, you won't be able to iterate through this normally, unless you specifically set your start value to `-1`, and the value at `-1` *very probably* (don't quote me on this) won't be reflected in the array's `length` property.

If you're interested, the ECMAScript specification for Arrays is here:

- http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array-objects

and the *length*  property of Array instances is defined here:

- http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length

Comment: Yeah it's not accounted for in the `length`

Comment: Cool! Thanks for checking, @Guig.

Comment: and doing `a[6] = 1;` would increase the length to 7, even the keys `3, 4, 5` are not included in the object.

Comment: @Guig—perhaps what you're replying to has been deleted. The *length* property is always *at least* one greater than the largest index. If an array has an index of 5, then adding indexes lower than 5 will not affect the *length* (which will be at least 6, perhaps larger, regardless of whether there are any indexes less than 5).

Comment: @Guig: What RobG said. And a property is considered to be an *index* if is numerical value is between `0` and `2^32-2` (not 100% sure about the upper limit, that might also have changed in the latest spec).